# How do I install Windows 7 on a HP Stream 11 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I tried to install windows 7 on my laptop but it says you need a Windows SD host controller driver, I got a driver and the installer for windows 7 searched the folder but wouldn't use it.

Can someone tell me where to put the driver or if there are other steps?

Answer (score -1):

Most original operating systems of HP (hp) laptops are win8.1 operating systems. To change the pre-installed win8.1 to win7, you need to set the BIOS.

Note: The following settings change UEFI+GPT to Legacy+MBR, and the hard disk partition table format needs to be converted. The entire hard drive data will be lost, need to be backed up.

1. Restart the laptop. Press F10 to enter the BIOS setup when the boot screen appears. For other models, press ESC and press F10.
2. Move to System Configuration, select Boot Options, press Enter to enter.
3. Select Legacy Support, press Enter to change to “Enabled”, and then change Secure Boot to “Disabled”.
4. Press F10 to save the BIOS settings and exit.
5. insert the U disk boot disk, press F9 while restarting the system, select the U disk option in the Boot Manager such as KingstonData, press Enter.
6. If the original win7 is installed, press Shift+F10 on the installation interface to bring up the command prompt.
7. Enter the following commands in turn, each command must be executed by pressing Enter, and the hard disk is changed to MBR format.

Diskpart

List disk

Select disk 0

Clean

Convert mbr

Exit

8. return to the installation interface, re-partition the hard disk for installation.